# Voltage across resistor for nodes

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage

[image]

What would the voltage be at nodes A and B? Would A = 10 V and B = 10V - voltage drop across R1? Also, when the voltage across R1 is given, would that be equal to the voltage at node A or node B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, generally a location in a circuit is designated to be zero reference voltage and then the voltages elsewhere in the circuit are measured with respect to that zero voltage reference point. Although as @Krishna pointed out theoretically the selection of the zero reference voltage is arbitrary, there are logical reasons for selecting a particular point.

For example, in the case of battery powered circuits the logical place would be at the negative terminal of the battery. That's because the positive terminal of the battery is, by convention, considered to be at higher potential than the negative terminal. So in your circuit the negative terminal of the battery would typically be chosen as zero potential. In which case the voltage at A would be +10 volts and at B 0 volts.

In the case of most general ac power systems in the world, the logical selection for zero potential is the earth. Most ac power systems in the world are connected (referenced) to the earth by means of one or more conducting elements referred to as a "grounding electrode" at different locations in the system. Keeping the power system near earth potential helps to protect the system from voltage surges that can damage the system, such as from lightning strikes. Moreover, the surface of the earth is generally considered to be negatively charged.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. "The voltage at node A" is only a defined quantity if you have already defined a reference node. The node you'll measure all other nodes' voltages relative to. You haven't told us what you chose as the reference node in this problem, so as far as we're concerned, "the voltage at node A" and "the voltage at node B" are undefined quantities.
2. Nodes A and B aren't only connected to the resistor R1. They're also connected to the battery. And it's very likely that your model of a battery at this point will tell you immediately what is the voltage difference between nodes A and B. Once you know that you only have to choose a reference node and do a **very** small amount of algebra to find the voltages of the two nodes individually.